# Remove the Duplicate strings in a file using Perl

Tags: perl

I want to do the following for some strings in a text file.  I got help with the basic functionality I needed, but now I want to sort the lines which are repeated and print them only once.

I want to remove Z , ZN and LVT from the string and sort them.

Input:

```
     abchsfk/jshflka/ZN                       (cellLVT)
     abchsfk/jshflka/ZN                       (cellLVT)

     asjkfsa/sfklfkshfsf/Z                    (mobLVT)
     asjkfsa/sfklfkshfsf/Z                    (mobLVT)

     asjhfdjkfd/sjfdskjfhdk/hsakfshf/Z        (celLVT)
     asjhfdjkfd/sjfdskjfhdk/hsakfshf/Z        (celLVT)

     asjhdjs/jhskjds/ZN                       (abcLVT)
     asjhdjs/jhskjds/ZN                       (abcLVT)

     shdsjk/jhskd/ZN                          (xyzLVT)
     shdsjk/jhskd/ZN                          (xyzLVT)
```

Desired Output:

```
   abchsfk/jshflka                     cell

   asjkfsa/sfklfkshfsf                 mob

   asjhfdjkfd/sjfdskjfhdk/hsakfshf     cel

   asjhdjs/jhskjds                     abc

   shdsjk/jhskd                        xyz
```

Code:

```
     if ($line =~ /LVT/ && ($line =~ /ZN/ || $line =~ /Z/) )        

          ####  matches the words LVT and ( Z or ZN)

      {   
             $line =~ s/\/ZN?|\(|LVT\)//g;

            my @line_out = $line;

            $lvt_out = sort::$line_out();

            print OUT " $lvt_out \n";

     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't actually sorting anything there. To get your output:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %seen;

while ( my $line = <DATA> ) {
    if ( $line =~ /LVT/ && ( $line =~ /ZN/ || $line =~ /Z/ ) )
        ####  matches the words LVT and ( Z or ZN)
    {
        $line =~ s/\/ZN?|\(|LVT\)//g;
        print $line unless $seen{$line}++;
    }
}

__DATA__
abchsfk/jshflka/ZN                       (cellLVT)
abchsfk/jshflka/ZN                       (cellLVT)

asjkfsa/sfklfkshfsf/Z                    (mobLVT)
asjkfsa/sfklfkshfsf/Z                    (mobLVT)

asjhfdjkfd/sjfdskjfhdk/hsakfshf/Z        (celLVT)
asjhfdjkfd/sjfdskjfhdk/hsakfshf/Z        (celLVT)

asjhdjs/jhskjds/ZN                       (abcLVT)
asjhdjs/jhskjds/ZN                       (abcLVT)

shdsjk/jhskd/ZN                          (xyzLVT)
shdsjk/jhskd/ZN                          (xyzLVT)
```

This gives:

```
abchsfk/jshflka                       cell
asjkfsa/sfklfkshfsf                    mob
asjhfdjkfd/sjfdskjfhdk/hsakfshf        cel
asjhdjs/jhskjds                       abc
shdsjk/jhskd                          xyz
```

If you were serious about sorting them though - what criteria were you using? A simple alphanumeric sort:

```
print sort keys %seen;
```

Gives:

```
abchsfk/jshflka                       cell
asjhdjs/jhskjds                       abc
asjhfdjkfd/sjfdskjfhdk/hsakfshf        cel
asjkfsa/sfklfkshfsf                    mob
shdsjk/jhskd                          xyz
```

Comment: Thank you. I just want to remove the repeated ones. No specific sequence for it.

Comment: Then you may wish to amend your question, because you do say "... and sort them".

Comment: You could write this as `if ( $line =~ s/\/ZN?|\(|LVT\)//g ) { ... }`

Answer (score 4):

This is simply done using `map` together with `uniq` from [`List::MoreUtils`](http://metacpan.org/module/List::MoreUtils). I see from your comment that you don't actually want to sort this data so I have left that out

This program expects the path to the input file as a parameter on the command line

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::MoreUtils qw/ uniq /;

my @rows = uniq map { m| ([\w/]+)/ZN? \s+ \((\w+)LVT\) |x ? "$1\t$2" : () } <>;

printf "%-31s %s\n", split /\t/ for @rows;
```

#### output

```
abchsfk/jshflka                 cell
asjkfsa/sfklfkshfsf             mob
asjhfdjkfd/sjfdskjfhdk/hsakfshf cel
asjhdjs/jhskjds                 abc
shdsjk/jhskd                    xyz
```